# How to cut a texture into disjoint sets?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d, texture-mapping

I am making a game, and I need to cut a 2D texture into multiple disjoint meshs, like a broken window glass. Is there any tool that permit to do that, that generates as outputs the different images, or triangles positions?

The problem by doing that by hand in e.g. GIMP is that it's not very precise (and tedious), it's hard to make that the edges don't overlap. Maybe there is a tool like that in GIMP, but I didn't found it.

[image]

Comment: Looks similar to a [Voronoi Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).

Comment: Wow, I didn't thought about it! I think it's a good search path, thanks you. Plus, with the Voronoi diagram, it's very easy to find the center.

Comment: please clarify: are you looking to put the textures of multiple meshes in a single image? if that's the case, that picture doesn't represent the idea. if the picture DOES represent the idea, please explain how those fragments relate to any textured meshes.

Comment: I'm looking to a way of, from a given image (like the one in the image) and the position of the edges (red lines) as inputs, split it in multiple images and generate as output the images parts (9 different images for the example) of minimal size, filled with transparent background. Actually, its the opposite: I want a way to split the big image, but without the hassle of manipulating the pixels, but just the edges.

Comment: Basically, the edges form a planar rect mesh because I don't want any overlap nor exclude a part of the image.

Comment: Imagine breaking a stained glass. I want, to pre-generate each broken part in its own image.

Comment: I don't see the problem. that thing _IS_ the texture you need for your geometry. just use the same image for multiple models, but define the texture coordinates appropriately. -- please try to clarify in a way that's not rephrasing but actually adding information you haven't disclosed yet. be specific, give examples. don't be abstract.